# How to replace an 8-pin relay with a 10-pin relay?

Tags: relay

I've been trying to reproduce the results of some experiments included in the *Make: Electronics* book by Charles Platt where 8-pin relays are used. The thing is that I haven't found DPDT 9V 8-pin relay as suggested in the book, and I only found 10-pin 9V relays. In the image below I show how the 8-pin relay is supposed to work and the schematics of the 10-pin relay I have.

[image: Schematics of the 8 and 10 pin relays]

What should I do with the 2 extra pins in my relay? Can someone help me understand how to connect the 10-pin relay to replace the 8-pin relay?

Answer (score 0):

The diagrams shown on the relays are showing how the **common** terminals (poles) can be switched between two other terminals (throws).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3d3dB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the above schematic, I've shown a single SPDT (single-pole double-throw) switch. It differs a bit from the relay diagrams in that 1) arrows are used instead of circles; and 2) two such switches are actuated simultaneously (hence the dual-pole dual-throw designation).

The line connecting the pole to Throw 1 can be interpreted as the "normally closed" position, so you could also treat Throw 1 as "NC" and Throw 2 as "normally open" or "NO".

It would be more clear to draw your original relay without crossing the inputs, but all you really need to do is map which pins serve which function:

On the original relay:

- Pin 2 is common, pins 4 and 2 are its throws;
- Pin 7 is common, pins 5 and 7 are its throws;
- Pins 1 and 8 are the coil.

On the new relay, ***assuming you have a single side stable variant***:

- Pin 3 is common, pins 2 (NC) and 4 (NO) are its throws;
- Pin 8 is common, pins 9 (NC) and 7 (NO) are its throws;
- Pins 1 and 10 are the coil;
- Pins 5 and 6 are not used and may be left unconnected.

I am interpreting the three symbols on your new relay as variations because the coil is shown as being connected to different pins. (e.g. the coil is between pins 1 and 10 in the first two diagrams while in the third diagram you can latch it one way using pins 6 and 10, and latch it the other way using pins 5 and 1.)

If you have a part number for the new relay, try looking for a datasheet from the manufacturer which may give better details.

Failing that, use a multimeter to check for resistance/continuity on the pins and verify which pins are wired to the coil.

**TL;DR**

On the 10-pin relay:

- Connect (+) to pin 1
- Connect (-) to pin 10
- Connect meter between pins 7 and 8.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have misunderstood the pin functions.

[image]

Pins 3 and 8 are the **common** pins. I've drawn in the contact "rocked" into the energised position where 3 contacts 4 and 8 contacts 7.